# Tag wikis and plagiarism

Tags: support

This is a reminder that the standard StackExchange rules on plagiarism apply to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts.

Please do not copy them from other web pages, even if they are short. As well as being against the rules, these generic summaries are often not helpful for explaining to people how the tag is used on this site.

When reviewing these edits, it is important to check for plagiarism; at least do a quick web search for the new text.

If you come across existing tag wiki material that has been plagiarised then please edit it out and explain why in the edit summary.

There's a general StackExchange guide on writing good tag wikis [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/132930).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for reminding the policy. Plagiarism gets tricky for small wiki excerpts.

For instance, my following wiki edit for [wise](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wise) got [rejected](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/90024) for plagiarism:

> Wise is a London-based financial technology company.

as the sentence appears on [over 20 websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Wise+is+a+London-based+financial+technology+company.%22).

I tried to rephrase as follows:

> Wise is a financial technology company based in London.

but it also appears on [a website](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Wise+is+a+financial+technology+company+based+in+London.%22)

I tried to rephrase again as follows:

> Wise is a financial technology company.

but it also appears on [over 50 websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Wise+is+a+financial+technology+company.%22)

I tried to rephrase again as follows:

> Wise is a fintech company.

but it also appears on [over 30 websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Wise+is+a+fintech+company.%22)

etc.

I found [What is the smallest amount of text that can be plagiarized?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/7648/3897), but there's no clear answers.

In the case where a wiki excerpt exists on another SE but not here, that'd be convenient to have a way to copy the wiki excerpt (if also relevant here) while keeping the attributions.

Comment: To be honest that excerpt isn't very useful anyway however it's phrased. Does it matter where they're based? More useful text might focus on identifying them more precisely and saying why people might be asking questions about them (e.g. "Wise, formerly known as Transferwise, is a fintech that provides foreign exchange and other banking services"). Or maybe we should just delete the tag as the only question that uses it isn't really about it anyway, it's just an example.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I mostly wanted to distinguish it from the adjective wise. I agree your excerpt is better.